# c++ How to check if there is a file in a directory quick way?

Tags: c++, file, directory

What I am trying to do is that when a directory has no write permission and if directory contains at least one file trying to print out "permission denied"

```
DIR *dir;
dir = opendir (argv[i]);
if (!(sb.st_mode & S_IWUSR) && (readdir(dir) != NULL))
{
    printf("rm: cannot remove ");
    printf(argv[i]);
    printf(": Permission denied\n"); 
}
```

This is what I was trying to do, but it prints out the messages even when there is no files... Any suggestions?

Comment: `readdir()` will always return at least 2 entries, the `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: `printf(argv[i])` should be `printf("%s", argv[i])`. But you should just combine all 3 into a single call to `printf` with a `%s` in the middle.

Comment: And there are a lot of other reasons other than `!(sb.st_mode & S_IWUSR)` that could cause an `rm` of any type to fail with "permission denied". It could be a read-only filesystem. In general, there is nothing to be gained in checking to see if an action would succeed before trying that action - even if you accurately duplicate any and all checks on that action (you *won't*), [you still introduce a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  If you need to remove a file - **remove the file**. The removal will either work or it won't. Don't check if you can first.